# Let R be the region bounded by the x-axis and the graph of y=cos( x)

Tags: calculus, integration

Let R be the region bounded by the x-axis and the graph of y=cos( x) between pi/2 and 3 pi/2 . Evaluate the integral R ( y2 sin3( x)+1)dA . Hint: Use symmetry.

I am kind of confused by the means of "use symmetry" for this problem, what I think it is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKNWU.gif

Is this correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: So $$R=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{3\pi}{2},~\cos(x)\leq y\leq 0\right\}$$ and you're trying to evaluate $$\iint_R (y^2\sin^3(x)+1)~dA~?$$

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your limits in the second integral where switched.

Note that $\cos x \le 0 $ for $ \pi /2 \le x \le 3\pi /2$

Thus $$\iint_R (y^2\sin^3(x)+1)~dA~=\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi /2} \int _{\cos x}^{0} (y^2\sin^3(x)+1)~dydx~$$